# Required steps to show User Location in MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkusertrackingmode

I have a mapView embedded in a View Controller that I would like to show the user's location.  While the following compiles, the map after loading does nothing and does not show the user's location. I tried the code first in viewDidLoad and then in viewDidFishingLoadingMap as I read that you need to let the map load first but it still does nothing.

Are there any additional steps beyond setting the tracking mode to get the map to center on the user's location? I have found [various approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443342/how-to-display-user-location-in-mapkit) in Objective-C using `mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;` or `[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];`
} but the following seems to be recommended for Swift.

```
func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView){
        mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.follow, animated:true)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Enable user location with Interface Builder or code [image]
- Add a `Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description` (or any other location usage mode you prefer) key to the **info.plist** file
- Import `CoreLocation`
- Check authorization status and prompt user if needed for location access.

**Swift**

```
if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
    CLLocationManager().requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}
```

**Objective-c**

```
[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

Comment: how do I enable user location

Comment: I add a screenshot

Comment: would you mind telling me how to do it in Swift code?

Comment: `mapView.showsUserLocation = true`

Please don't forget to upvote this comment and the answer if you find them useful. ;) Tnx